# How to determine that the user did not press any button for some time

Tags: ios, user-interface, timer, uigesturerecognizer

I have several setting panels and buttons on the screen. I need to hide them, when the user did not tap/press any button during the last 5 seconds.
How can I do this? How can I determine that no actions were made during some period?

Comment: Have you had any ideas? Tried anything?

Comment: give some tag to all your buttons and set same action to all buttons, whenever user clicks buttons, action will be fired, store the tags in an array.after 5 sec you can check in array.

Comment: I need to know if the user did not touch anything, didn't even tapped the screen.

Comment: you can assign tag to all view in the view hierarchy and using gesture you can track tap also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a method to hide your button, let name it `hideButtons`, you can perform a selector after a delay to hide your button :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideButtons) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

And in the method associated to your `UIGestureRecognizer`, cancel it

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
//next line only if you want to restart counting no action performed for 5 sec.
[self performSelector:@selector(hideButtons) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

Comment: I used this one and it works just right how I needed it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There are simple steps you can follow to achieve this -

- Show the view of buttons
- Start an NSTimer
- If any button is pressed, in action of button restart the NSTimer
- Else after 5 seconds hide the view and remove it from superview then invalidate your NSTimer.

Good Luck!